# Magento category edit page and ajax

Tags: magento

I am adding some extra html to some input attributes in the category edit area by creating a new attribute input renderer type in my modules mysql install script:

```
$installer->addAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'mymodule_category_popularity',
    array(
        'label' => 'My Label',
        'group' => 'My Group',   
        'type'  => 'int',
        'class' => 'validate-number',
        'required' => false,
        'default' => 50,
        'input_renderer' => 'mymodule/adminhtml_catalog_category_widget_slider',
    )
);
```

And the renderer:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Widget_Slider extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {

        $html = parent::getAfterElementHtml();
        return $html."  <div id=\"slider\"></div>";
    }
}
```

And the javascript:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){  

     $j( "#slider" ).slider();

});
```

This works fine, the plugins get loaded correctly and so does jQuery (as I have loaded it using my layout xml for the module). I see a slider. However, after the page has completely finished (the Magento ajax has re-loaded the category edit tabs) my slider dissapears. This, I assume, is because the javascript code is not getting ran again.

I have tried adding my javascript to the core edit.phtml (as there is other Magento JS there) however I just get an error: `$j('#slider).slider() is not a function`. This is because the content is getting loaded via ajax.

So, how do I make sure that I can use `$j('#slider).slider()` in the category edit area? Confusing I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by creating a javascript function:

```
function loadedInput() {
    $('#slider').slider();
}
```

And calling that function in the attribute renderer:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Category_Widget_Slider extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {

        $html = parent::getAfterElementHtml();
        return $html."  <div id=\"slider\"></div><script>loadedInput();</script>";
    }
}
```